# PowerShell script to use excels TextToColumns Feature

Tags: excel, powershell

I've been trying to implement the function Range.TextToColumns() but I can't seem to get it to work. I can do this manually in excel and it works fine. (Data tab -> Data tools group -> "Text to Columns" -> Select Date on 3rd step, MDY)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193593(v=office.14).aspx

I am trying to convert a US date format into a UK date format using PowerShell. I want an excel solution rather than exporting all the dates into PowerShell then sending them back into the spreadsheet.

Here is my attempt

**dateConversion.ps1**

```
$excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $True
$excel.Visible = $True

$wb = $excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\danny\Desktop\datesUS.csv")
$ws = $wb.WorkSheets.Item(1)

#r,c
$dateColumn = $ws.Range($ws.Cells.Item(2, 1), $ws.Cells.Item(7, 1))
$destination = $ws.Cells.Item(2, 3)
$dateColumn.TextToColumns($destination, 1, -4142, $False, $False, $False, $False, $False, $False, @(1, 3))

#$excel.Quit()
```

**dateUS.csv**

```
date,dateName
1/29/2013,29th Jan
6/18/2012,18th June
6/28/2012,28th June
7/27/2012,27th July
8/1/2012,1st Aug
8/20/2012,20th Aug
```

It seems to copy the same date to the destination instead of doing a conversion.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you to do the operation inside excel, I'd recommend using a macro instead. For a solution like the one above where you open and close a com-instance of excel, you should skip COM and use `import-csv`. It's more "foolproof".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an odd error/exception.

There's two things I had to do to get this to work. It seems that I had to manually specify the Range for the destination *in* the TextToColumns function call. And that opened up the OtherChar field so that it could be specified as "3", which then made it work.

It seems like the bug is the array that you "think" you are specifying for the field info may have been interpreted as an OtherChar field... which isn't available unless you manually specify the Range manually, and not through a variable. (Weird and odd, I know, but it works):

Change your TextToColumns call to this:

```
$dateColumn = $ws.Range($ws.Cells.Item(2, 1), $ws.Cells.Item(7, 1))
$dateColumn.TextToColumns($ws.Range($ws.Cells.Item(2,3),$ws.Cells.Item(7,3)), 1, -4142, $False, $False, $False, $False, $False, $False, 3, @(1,3))
```